# Не понятно работающая логика удаления объекта

Tags: c++, asio

Изучаю работу простого сервера на boos::asio.
Один из примеров работы с ним я нашел тут:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp
Однако в примере мне не понятно поведение программы в функции void do_accept(),
а именно в строке

```
if(!ec){
    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
}
```

Тут создается shared_ptr и у объекта вызывается метод start. После выхода из блока этот умный указатель должен быть уничтожен, однако этого не происходит.
В чем причина?

Answer (score 0):

> После выхода из блока этот умный указатель должен быть уничтожен, однако этого не происходит. В чем причина?

В `start` мы начинаем читать данные с сокета:

```
socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            do_write(length);
        }
    });
```

, и, если Вы посмотрите на обработчик (это лямбда-функция в примере выше), то увидите, что self передается в capture list лямба-функции - таким образом мы создаем копию текущего `std::shared_ptr<Session>`, соответственно, объект продолжает себе спокойно жить дальше.

P.S. Объект обработчика не хранится в `_socket` (хотя, по коду так может показаться).

---

> Все равно не понятно. Объект самого умного указателя создается в do_connect. Откуда объект из do_read знает что в методе do_connect есть экземпляр?

В Вашем примере я вообще `do_connect` не вижу. `do_read` это член-функция `session`, внутри нее мы создаем копию текущего `std::shared_ptr<session>` и передаем ее в обработчик. Вы спрашиваете, "Откуда объект из do_read знает..." - так это один и тот же объект, мы у него и вызываем `do_read`.

Comment: Главную (в контексте вопроса) строчку забыли: `auto self(shared_from_this());`

Comment: Все равно не понятно. Объект самого умного указателя создается в do_connect.
Откуда объект из do_read знает что в методе do_connect есть экземпляр?

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый Находясь в методе объекта находящегося под управлением умным указателем, можно получить копию умного указателя: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this

Comment: @Chorkov, да я, честно говоря, и не думал об этом - словами поведение я описал, а код у автора вопроса и так под рукой есть.